HCL commerce V9.1 liberty server startup error- wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found
Hi all Thanks for your help in advance. I am using HCL commerce V9.1 commerce application ad trying to start liberty search server. ON startup i am getting below error stack. IN this the file mentioned wc-config-mapping-registry.xml. I could see this file at right location under folder C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\resources\search\runtime\config\com.ibm.commerce.foundation. not we have ext folder as well next to it. Error stack is as below.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 52897
Launching searchServer (WebSphere Application Server 23.0.0.6/wlp-1.0.78.cl230620230612-1100) on IBM J9 VM, version 8.0.8.20 - pwa6480sr8fp20-20240112_01(SR8 FP20) (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server searchServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\configDropins\overrides\datasources.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\configDropins\overrides\jndi.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\configDropins\overrides\logging.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\configDropins\overrides\userregistry.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/activation-1.1.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cache-api-1.0.0.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cf-base-9.1-20200614.194457-11.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/checker-qual-2.0.0.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec-1.0.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/geronimo-jaxrs_1.1_spec-1.0.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/guava-25.1-jre.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jackson-core-2.10.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jaxb-api-2.2.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jboss-marshalling-2.0.9.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jboss-marshalling-river-2.0.9.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jodd-bean-5.0.13.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jodd-core-5.0.13.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jsr305-3.0.2.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-buffer-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-codec-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-handler-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-resolver-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/reactor-core-3.3.4.RELEASE.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/redisson-3.13.0.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/rxjava-2.2.19.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/snakeyaml-1.26.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/stax-api-1.0-2.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/wink-client-1.4.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\hcl-cache-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/wink-common-1.4.jar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKM0101E: The system could not process archive data for C:\WCDE_V9\workspace\search-ear\lib\rome-1.12.2.jar!/rome-utils-1.12.2.jar.
[EL Info]: server: 2024-05-13 19:03:46.319--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.was.WebSphere_Liberty_Platform.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/solr/
[EL Info]: server: 2024-05-13 19:03:56.387--ServerSession(-961645421)--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.was.WebSphere_Liberty_Platform.
[WARNING ] CWWJP9991W: [eclipselink.server] Failed to find MBean Server: null or empty List returned from MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null)
[WARNING ] CWWJP9991W: [eclipselink.metamodel] The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either  elements or a global false element
[ERROR   ] CWNCF5040E: Application failed. Details:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:157)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:146)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadFoundationConfig(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:111)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:58)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.myGetNewProperties(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1006)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.refreshDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1159)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.myRefreshInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.getInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:198)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationInfo.getDelayAfterInvalidationMilliseconds(CacheConfigurationInfo.java:368)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.initializeDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1119)
at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.TransactionServletContextListener.contextInitialized(TransactionServletContextListener.java:39)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2468)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp31.java:512)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1066)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6706)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:474)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:469)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1197)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:986)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:101)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:51)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:599)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.installApp(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:513)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:351)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:184)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1369)
at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:912)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:247)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
Caused by: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0008E: The file config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation\wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found in directory config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.util.FileHelper.(FileHelper.java:62)
... 31 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:157)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:146)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadFoundationConfig(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:111)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:58)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.myGetNewProperties(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1006)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.refreshDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1159)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.myRefreshInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.getInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:198)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationInfo.getDelayAfterInvalidationMilliseconds(CacheConfigurationInfo.java:368)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.initializeDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1119)
at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.TransactionServletContextListener.contextInitialized(TransactionServletContextListener.java:39)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2468)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0008E: The file config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation\wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found in directory config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.util.FileHelper.(FileHelper.java:62)
... 12 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [SolrSearchServlet] in application [search-ear]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:107)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.servlet.solr.SolrSearchServlet.init(SolrSearchServlet.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:301)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0008E: The file config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation\wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found in directory config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.util.FileHelper.(FileHelper.java:62)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadFoundationConfig(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:111)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:58)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.myGetNewProperties(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1006)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.refreshDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1159)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.myRefreshInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.getInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:198)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationInfo.getDelayAfterInvalidationMilliseconds(CacheConfigurationInfo.java:368)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.initializeDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1119)
at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.TransactionServletContextListener.contextInitialized(TransactionServletContextListener.java:39)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2468)
... 1 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [SolrSearchServlet]: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:370)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:107)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.services.search.servlet.solr.SolrSearchServlet.init(SolrSearchServlet.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:301)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0008E: The file config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation\wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found in directory config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.util.FileHelper.(FileHelper.java:62)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadFoundationConfig(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:111)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:58)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.myGetNewProperties(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1006)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.refreshDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1159)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.myRefreshInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.getInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:198)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationInfo.getDelayAfterInvalidationMilliseconds(CacheConfigurationInfo.java:368)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.initializeDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1119)
at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.TransactionServletContextListener.contextInitialized(TransactionServletContextListener.java:39)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2468)
... 1 more
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application search-ear has not started in 30.092 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-2.0, concurrent-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrs-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, jdbc-4.1, jndi-1.0, jpa-2.1, jpaContainer-2.1, json-1.0, jsonp-1.0, jsp-2.3, localConnector-1.0, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, usr:hcl-cache-1.0, usr:micrometer-1.3.5, webCache-1.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The searchServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The searchServer server started in 42.042 seconds.
[WARNING ] XML parse warning in "solrres:/../../../v3-index-ext/CatalogGroup/x-solrconfig.xml", line 3, column 69: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href=''). Reason: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\resources\search\index\managed-solr\config\v3\CatalogGroup\conf......\v3-index-ext\CatalogGroup
[WARNING ] XML parse warning in "solrres:/../../../v3-index-ext/CatalogEntry/x-solrconfig.xml", line 3, column 69: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href=''). Reason: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\resources\search\index\managed-solr\config\v3\CatalogEntry\conf......\v3-index-ext\CatalogEntry
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieFloatField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieIntField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieLongField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieDoubleField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieDateField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[ERROR   ] SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!
[ERROR   ] Error closing IndexWriter
java.lang.NullPointerException
[WARNING ] XML parse warning in "solrres:/../../../v3-index-ext/Unstructured/x-solrconfig.xml", line 3, column 69: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href=''). Reason: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\resources\search\index\managed-solr\config\v3\Unstructured\conf......\v3-index-ext\Unstructured
[WARNING ] XML parse warning in "solrres:/../../../v3-index-ext/Inventory/x-solrconfig.xml", line 3, column 69: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href=''). Reason: C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\Liberty\usr\servers\searchServer\resources\search\index\managed-solr\config\v3\Inventory\conf......\v3-index-ext\Inventory
[WARNING ] Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.StandardRequestHandler]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [SolrRequestFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [SolrRequestFilter]: could not be initialized
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/search/previewresources/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [HttpSecurityFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [HttpSecurityFilter]: com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.HttpSecurityFilter was found, but is missing another required class.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/search/resources/
[WARNING ] Method findCustomSuggestions in com.ibm.commerce.search.rest.SiteContentResource has no JAX-RS Path or HTTP Method annotations
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [HttpSecurityFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [HttpSecurityFilter]: com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.HttpSecurityFilter was found, but is missing another required class.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/search/admin/resources/
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:107)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.servlet.SearchSchedulerServletListener.contextInitialized(SearchSchedulerServletListener.java:135)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2468)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0008E: The file config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation\wc-config-mapping-registry.xml was not found in directory config/com.ibm.commerce.foundation.
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.util.FileHelper.(FileHelper.java:62)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadFoundationConfig(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:111)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:101)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:58)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.myGetNewProperties(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1006)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.refreshDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1159)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.myRefreshInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationCache.getInstance(CacheConfigurationCache.java:198)
at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheConfigurationInfo.getDelayAfterInvalidationMilliseconds(CacheConfigurationInfo.java:368)
at com.ibm.commerce.search.internal.cache.SearchCacheConfiguration.initializeDataCache(SearchCacheConfiguration.java:1119)
at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.TransactionServletContextListener.contextInitialized(TransactionServletContextListener.java:39)
... 2 more
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [HttpSecurityFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [HttpSecurityFilter]: com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.HttpSecurityFilter was found, but is missing another required class.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/search/ext/resources/
[WARNING ] Method findCustomSuggestions in com.ibm.commerce.search.rest.SiteContentResource has no JAX-RS Path or HTTP Method annotations
[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [HttpSecurityFilter] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [HttpSecurityFilter]: com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.HttpSecurityFilter was found, but is missing another required class.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ddc2-l-9knwhg3.dir.svc.accenture.com:3737/monitor/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application search-ear started in 149.733 seconds.
I have tried clean publish. Verfied the missing file path. All looks good to me but yet not able to resolve the issue
